# \paragraph{...} right after \begin{proof}

Tags: amsmath, environments, paragraphs

I love the \paragraph{...} command, but if I use it right after \begin{proof} it does not work.

Is there a way to define my own paragraph-command such that I can use it right after \begin{proof}.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\jot}{12pt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\newtheoremstyle{my_theorem_style}
  {20pt}{20pt}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{.}%
  {\newline}{}%

\theoremstyle{my_theorem_style}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum.

\begin{theorem}
Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas:
%
\begin{enumerate}
\item Nunc vel risus commodo.
\item Libero nunc consequat.
\item Diam maecenas sed enim ut. 
\end{enumerate}
%
\end{theorem}


\begin{proof}...
%
\paragraph{ad 1.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. 

\paragraph{ad 2.} Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. 

\paragraph{ad 3.} Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non. 
%
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use \paragraph{...} right after \begin{proof} it wont even compile.

So I alsways have to write something (sometimes bs) right after \begin{proof}.

Comment: How exactly are you defining the `proof` environment? What should the output look like?

Comment: What exactly do you like about \paragraph?  Do you include the paragraph numbers in the table of contents?  (The TOC normally stops at subsections.)

Comment: I like that (1) I dont have to take care of vertical space manually, (2) I dont have to use \textbf{...} manually. I do not include any paragraphs numerbers in the TOC.

Comment: The `proof` env here is made via a list, and `\paragraph` cannot start a list. In a number of book I've used a homepage macro that for the first use inside proof will use `*something*` and for later uses in the same proof will use `\paragraph` internally.

Comment: It might be easier to just start the proof by `We prove each item separately. \paragraph{Ad...}`

Comment: imho you are misusing a heading command for a visual effect, but from the technical side this is the problem described in this issue https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/553

Answer (score 1):

I think that the macro `mypara` defined below does what you want. It gives a `\paragraph` looking output but has no numbering or ToC entry.

```
% paraprob.tex  SE 620506

\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\jot}{12pt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\newtheoremstyle{my_theorem_style}
  {20pt}{20pt}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{.}%
  {\newline}{}%

\theoremstyle{my_theorem_style}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\mypara}[1]{%
\vspace{\parskip}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textbf{#1 }%
}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum.

\begin{theorem}
Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas:
%
\begin{enumerate}
\item Nunc vel risus commodo.
\item Libero nunc consequat.
\item Diam maecenas sed enim ut. 
\end{enumerate}
%
\end{theorem}


\begin{proof}...
%
\paragraph{ad 1.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. 

\paragraph{ad 2.} Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. 

\paragraph{ad 3.} Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non. 
%
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}...

\mypara{ad 1.} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. 

\mypara{ad 2.} Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id volutpat. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. 

\mypara{ad 3.} Habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non. 
%
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kinda Noob answer: but i find that putting in a
`$\;$\\`
often helps out.
This gives you a Math enviorment and just ads in a space with a line break after it. 
Basicly an empty row without using commands that dont work righ after each other.